# jsonObjectRequest error, always ends up on onErrorResponse method

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have the following portion of code which is a jsonObjectRequest but turns out it always ends up on onErrorReponseMethod instead of the onResponse method.

```
        String url = API.getDevices()+ id + "/events";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    processEvent(response, name, id);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("mytag", "Error de response");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Here's how things look in swagger

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

I think it's possible I need to do a string request since I get the following error in the logcat:

```
 com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 06-18 02:54:45.662 3222-3222/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

But in case I make a string request, how can I get the values for 'events' and 'args' of my response?

Comment: why does the response body in swagger ui has id: and data: prefix, it is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is not valid. Use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to generate a valid JSON.

Comment: But the API was provided to me, I cannot change it.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed then you will have to ask the provider of this API to use proper JSON